# ViewStub dont show

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-xml, viewstub

My ViewStub is not showing

```
<ViewStub
     android:id="@+id/hint"
     android:layout_width="500dp"
     android:layout_height="500dp"
     android:inflatedId="@+id/main_niht"
     android:layout="@layout/main_hint"
     app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Here is my ViewStub It is inside the main layout

In Oncreate I call this

```
b.hint.inflate()
b.hint.visibility = View.VISIBLE
```

But ViewStub still doesn't show like it never existed

Are there any tips on how to use it correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`inflate` replaces the `ViewStub` with the inflated view, so your call to set the visibility does nothing. If your inflated view starts invisible, that would explain your problem. You need to set the visibility on the inflated view, not the view stub.

```
val inflatedView = b.hint.inflate()
inflatedView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
```

If that doesn't work, use [Layout Inspector](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/layout-inspector) or show the layout of the view you're trying to inflate.

Comment: Your suggestion helped a lot, I put the ViewStub above all views so that nothing overlaps it and everything worked